# Provide definition of electric field at a point

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, definition

Source A: Electric field at a point P is defined as the influence a unit charge ($1\ C$)  would feel at that point.

Source B: Electric field at a point is defined as
$$\mathbf{E}= \lim_{q_0 \to 0} \frac{\mathbf{F}_e}{q_0}$$

Please tell which one is true.

Answer (score 1):

The one of source B is the more meaningful one. The electric field E(x) is the influence a TEST-PARTICLE would feel if it would be at x. It is important that the Charge placed at position x is very small (limit to zero), since you do not want it to change the physical situation by its charge. However, both are the same for most considered configurations. You can see that for example by looking at Coulomb Law.

Comment: Both appears to be same,but  test charge of 1C is more correct if see coulomb law